# MacOS Catalina Simulators Screen Saver capturing the same screen

Tags: ios, macos-catalina, screensaver

I am an iOS developer and I am using MacOS Catalina with Xcode 14.1.

After MacOS Catalina update and Xcode update, all simulators stops saving screen correctly.

Now, the simulator saves always the same screen, while I am navigating through all the screens of my app.

The simulator saves always the same first screen, everytime.

No matter what part of my app I am, when a click to save the current screen, it jumps back directly to the first screen it has captured, showing this first screen over my current screen, covering it and ignoring the current screen, and then, capturing this first screen again.

Is it one more Catalina MacOS bug ? Is there any fix ?

If there isn´t a fix now, is there any free option to substitute ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue with macOS Big Sur and Xcode v12.3

Comment: so it's not about catalina